# Send multiple variable to laravel Api resources

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, resources

I want to different type of collection..One containing users acros the city and another one containing near by users. I want these from single api hit. is it possible ? If yes then please suggest how to do that.

***Waht I did***

```
return  ServiceProviderCollection::collection($near_by);
```

**Output:**

```
"data": [
    {
        "username": "??",
        "email": "??",
        "rating": 0,
        "role_id": 2,
        "wallet": "0"
    }
],
```

***I want***

```
return  ServiceProviderCollection::collection($near_by,$across_city);
```

*expected output:*

```
{
    "across_city": {
        "data": [
            {
                "username": "??",
                "email": "??",
            }
        ],
    },
    "near_by": {
        "data": [
            {
                "username": "??",
                "email": "??",

            }
        ],

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the class `ServiceProviderCollection`? This does not seem to be part of Laravel itself.

Comment: Laravel's resources collection.  Collection resources extend the  Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection class. More ditails: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using Laravel 7 and in my controller I am passing an array of collection objects to resource class

```
 $data = ['quotation' => Quotation::first()]; 
 return new QuotationResource($data);
```

and in my resource class I can access the data using

```
   public function toArray($request)
   {
        return [
            'quotation' => $this->resource['quotation']
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't pass 2 objects in `Resource`. You can do it like this

```
return [
         'across_city' =>  ServiceProviderCollection::collection($across_city),
         'near_by' => ServiceProviderCollection::collection($near_by)
       ];
```

**Edit:** After comment

If you want to show pagination information then you have to create separate controller action and then return `ServiceProviderCollection::collection` then you will get result with pagination meta information.

create these action in your controller ex. (`UserController`)

```
public function acrossCity(){
   $acrossCity = User::where('city','test')->paginate(10); //example 

   return ServiceProviderCollection::collection($acrossCity);
}

public function nearBy(){
   $nearBy = User::where('near','1')->paginate(10); //example 

   return ServiceProviderCollection::collection($nearBy);
}
```

create routes for these

```
Route::get('user/acrossCity','UserController@acrossCity');
Route::get('user/nearBy','UserController@nearBy');
```

Check document https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#pagination

**Note:** when using resource class then name it without `Collection`. For your case you should name resource as `ServiceProviderResource` and then when you call its collection then `ServiceProviderResource::collection($object)` but when returning single object then `new ServiceProviderResource($object)`.

Comment: ServiceProviderCollection::collection($across_city)//paginate working. But when i am using your above code paginate working but not showing any meta value like current page,next page link etc.

Comment: @weaver If you want to show pagination information then you have to create separate controller action and then `return ServiceProviderCollection::collection` then you will get result with pagination meta information

Comment: @rkj..Thanks..I am trying to do so..Buti have zero idea how to do that.would you please explain in details?

Comment: You used two different routes. mean i can't get both result near_by and across_city at same time. i need both result on single route hit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179792/discussion-between-rkj-and-weaver).

Comment: check chat message